Typescript error in reassigning query variable at Supabase
I am using react and supabase. I have written the following code. I has job of updating or creating.

export const createEditCabin = async (newCabin: createCabinType, id?: number) => {
    let imagePath = "";
    let imageName = "";
    if (typeof newCabin.image === "object") {
        imageName = `${Math.floor(Math.random()) * 10}-${newCabin.image.name}`.replaceAll("/", "");
        imagePath = `${supabaseUrl}/storage/v1/object/public/cabin-images/${imageName}`;
    } else {
        imagePath = newCabin.image
    }

    let query =supabase.from("Cabins");


    // Create 
    if (!id) {
        query = supabase.from("Cabins").insert([
            { ...newCabin, image: imagePath }
        ]);
    }
    // Edit
    if (id) {
        query = supabase.from("Cabins")
            .update({ ...newCabin, image: imagePath })
            .eq('id', id);
    }

    const { data, error } = await query.select().single();
    return data;




When calling the createEditCabin function, the following typescript error appears for query:

Type 'PostgrestFilterBuilder<any, any, null, "Cabins", unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'PostgrestQueryBuilder<any, any, "Cabins", unknown>': insert, upsert, update, deletets(2739)

How can solve it?

It's because you are reusing query variable for select and mutating the data. You can try to separate the logic like:
export const createEditCabin = async (newCabin: createCabinType, id?: number) => {
    let imagePath = "";
    let imageName = "";
    if (typeof newCabin.image === "object") {
        imageName = `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)}-${newCabin.image.name}`.replaceAll("/", "");
        imagePath = `${supabaseUrl}/storage/v1/object/public/cabin-images/${imageName}`;
    } else {
        imagePath = newCabin.image;
    }

    if (!id) {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from("Cabins")
            .insert([{ ...newCabin, image: imagePath }])
            .select()
            .single();

        if (error) throw error;
        return data;
    }

    if (id) {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from("Cabins")
            .update({ ...newCabin, image: imagePath })
            .eq("id", id)
            .select()
            .single();

        if (error) throw error;
        return data;
    }

    return null;
};

